# Bootstrap Center Navbar Items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know I can push navbar items to the left and right, but how would I center them?

```
text-align:center;
```

doesn't work nor any of the other things I thought of.

Comment: We'll need to see more code. Can you share with us the relevant HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You will need to modify some CSS rules for Navbar component. So add a class `center` to `nav.navbar` and the following rules:

```
.navbar.center .navbar-inner {
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar.center .navbar-inner .nav {
    display:inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

**[Working demo (Bootstrap 3.3.7)](https://www.codeply.com/go/kF314O05E3)**

Comment: This works but adds a 7px margin below the navbar elements. Adding `height: 50px;` to the `.navbar.center .navbar-inner` block is hacky but works.

Comment: This also changes the width of the `li` elements when the screen is resized to a smaller width e.g. when the breakpoint kicks in. Is there a quick hack to get the width to be 100%?

Comment: Bootstrap 4.5.0 changes the `navbar-inner` class to `navbar-collapse` and somehow this solution doesn't work even after replacement. @Ania 's answer below works.

Answer (score 8):

To extend upon the selected answer, adding vertical align top will prevent the space from appearing under the nav items.

```
.navbar.center .navbar-inner {
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar.center .navbar-inner .nav {
    display:inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/tebukeyeci/1/edit?css,output)**

Answer (score 7):

I had similar problem. What worked for me is adding rule 'justify-content' like this:

CSS:

```
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-collapse {
display: flex!important;
justify-content: space-around;
flex-basis: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav id="hamburger" class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav center">
        <div><a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">
          Start <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </div>
        <div><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a></div>
        <div><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Blog</a></div>
        <div><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">O mnie</a></div>
        <div><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 6):

## Use `text-center` or `mx-auto` or `container-fluid` or use flexbox technique, `flex justify-center`

1. You could use this hack `text-center` (this does not only apply for text)
2. Or use the exact boostrap class `mx-auto`

example 
`class="text-center"` or  `class="mx-auto"`

in context

```html
<div class="btn-group text-center"> or <div class="btn-group mx-auto">
```

**TRY NOT TO USE** inline styles (bad practice)

```html
<div class="btn-group" style="margin:0 auto">
```

---

**References here:**

`text-center` => 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/

`mx-auto` => https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/#horizontal-centering

Comment: flex justify-center 
can you give an example ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
text-align:center;
```

to a wrapper element to center its childs, but only if the childs have

```
display: inline;
/* or */
display: inline-block;
```

Another option, if you know the width of the element you want to center, is

```
display: block;
width: /* something */;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add the `mx-auto` class to the element with the `navbar-nav` class. This will center the items automatically.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">...</li>
</ul>
```