# How do I center items of the navbar inside a full-width container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

So I am trying to make a Boostrap 4 navbar to fit in a full width container,but I want to navigation bar items to be centered, like in a normal container.

```html
 <div class="container-full">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  position'navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    </div>
```

I can't figure out what to modify.

Comment: which type of output you need ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838463/bootstrap-center-navbar-items

Comment: @Bhargav https://imgur.com/a/kO52D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place a .container inside the nav element:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-full">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  position'navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```