# How to put form element (search bar) into the center of the navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="/docs/4.4/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">Bootstrap</a>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I was trying to put  element in the center of the Navbar. But isn't placing in the center of the Navbar it places at the end of the Navbar. So how can I place this search bar in the center of the Navbar?[image: Search bar placing at the end of the Navbar]

Comment: You should include the relevant HTML and CSS in your question - a lazily taken screenshot of your browser isn't anything we can help with. Your question is required to contain a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Shiny sorry for misconduct just added the code sample. I hope you can help in this matter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap Center Navbar Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838463/bootstrap-center-navbar-items)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to center all the elements in the navbar, you can do that by using the `justify-content-center` class in the nav

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light justify-content-center">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="/docs/4.4/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">Bootstrap</a>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

If you are trying to move the search block to the middle of the navbar, you could add an empty `div` to the end of the `nav` block, and add the `justify-content-between` class to the `nav` element.

Disclaimer: This is not a very clean solution

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light justify-content-between">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="/docs/4.4/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">Bootstrap</a>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div></div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to review this website https://hackerthemes.com/bootstrap-cheatsheet/ and see the different types of navbar available, and understand the structure to move the search engine in the HTML.

Comment: This is not a full answer, it should have been placed as a comment. For a full answer, please suggest a concrete solution and add explanations.