# Bootstrap 4 Navbar search box not aligning in center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've gone through almost every question regarding center aligning elements in a navbar, haven't found an answer yet.

I've been trying to center align a search bar inside of my navbar but outside of the collapsible button. The problem is, no matter what I do, I can't get the search box in the center. It just stays to the left.

However, if I make the viewport smaller, as soon as the links on the right disappear inside the collapsible button, the search box aligns just fine in the center. Here's my Navbar code:

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Carousel</a>
    <form class="form-inline justify-content-center" style="text-align: center;">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2"type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Log in</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

I want the search box to be outside of the collapsible button but aligned in the center. I've tried adding `mx-auto` along with width but it doesn't work. I've tried dozens of other questions on SO, nothing's worked out yet.

I'm attaching screenshots for your reference
[image: That's how the navbar looks in full viewport width]
When in full width, the search bar doesn't center align

[image]
As soon as the collapsible button appears everything works just fine.

How do I get the search box aligned in the center?
Also, is there any way to increase the width of the search box without using explicit CSS styling, as that breaks the responsive behavior?

Comment: I'm not able to use a code editor at the moment but I think you should work with margins here and see how that helps. First try to add margin left auto to the form and then margin right auto... Bootstrap4 uses flex heavily and most times, auto margins solve the problem

Comment: @EmekeAjeh I tried. Makes no difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just answered a similar question at [How to put form element (search bar) into the center of the navbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59848572/how-to-put-form-element-search-bar-into-the-center-of-the-navbar)

You can align your search form to the center of the navbar in 2 steps.

- Wrap the search bar, and the collapsible menu on the right into separate parent `div`
- Add the `justify-content-between` class to the navbar

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark justify-content-between">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Carousel</a>
  <div>
    <form class="form-inline justify-content-center" style="text-align: center;">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Log in</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: "I want the search box to be outside of the collapsible button"

Comment: @NathanielFlick The search box is outside the collapsible button. I just moved the collapsible menu and the search bar into separate containers (div)

Comment: Check and see if OP wants the search field in with the nav items list?

Comment: @NathanielFlick I haven't changed how the page is laid out, just wrapped the 2 separate elements (nav items/search field) into 2 separate containers. which allows them to be spaced evenly.

Comment: Yeap that does it. Any idea how to increase the length of the box though?

Comment: @YaddyVirus Bootstrap [inline forms](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#inline-forms) use flexboxes.You can use the built in [flexbox utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink) class `flex-grow-1` to resize the input container `div` and the input.

Comment: @maverick Yep that's what I did. However, that aligns the search box in the middle of the navbar, which isn't exactly the middle of the viewport. Any fixes for that?